# Unreachable code detected WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, return, messagebox

This code will not continue if the IsDownloaded is True. How do I properly have a MessageBox pop if if False and Return;?  If I take out the 'Return;' RingToneTask  never occurs even if IsDownloaded is True.

```
private void ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone(string soundPath)
    {
        if (IsDownloaded == false)
            MessageBox.Show("Will not download until you short press atleast once");
        return;
        App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

            SaveRingtoneTask task = new SaveRingtoneTask();
            task.Source = new Uri("isostore:/" + this.SavePath);
            task.DisplayName = this.Title;
            task.Show();
        }
           );
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use an `if`-statement? In that case, please start by learning C#

Comment: Your question is totally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scope

```
private void ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone(string soundPath)
{
    if (IsDownloaded == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Will not download until you short press atleast once");
        return;
    }
    App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {

        SaveRingtoneTask task = new SaveRingtoneTask();
        task.Source = new Uri("isostore:/" + this.SavePath);
        task.DisplayName = this.Title;
        task.Show();
    }
       );
```

Comment: Also replace `if (IsDownloaded == false)` to `if (!IsDownloaded)` :-)